# When I set pub as a root directory under apache store code is merge without slash with url

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.6

When I set pub as a root directory in my system then store url merge without slash with url

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port t>
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    #ServerName www.example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/phil/pub/
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
</Directory>
```

url showing like http://127.0.0.1default/contact

Comment: make sure that the base url in core_config_data ends with a slash (`/`)

Comment: yes already put under base url "http://127.0.0.1/"

Comment: solved it was the cache issue, something happening due to cache

Comment: @AashutoshKumar Great. Could you add it to the answer section and mark it as an accepted answer to let others know the issue is solved?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it was the cache issue, something happening due to cache, after deploy it is showing ok.